# Can a single Spring application have two IoC containers?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Can a single Spring application have two(or more) IoC containers?

Comment: You can create as many as you want. We would need more context and information about your use case to be able to provide any more useful of an answer.

Comment: Thank, I am new to Spring. When I told one person I know Spring, he asked me - Can a(single) Spring Application have two IoC containers?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, they can.

According to [`Spring Framework reference documentation Version 5.0.8.RELEASE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/):

> The `org.springframework.beans` and `org.springframework.context`
>   packages are the basis for Spring Framework’s *IoC container*. 
>   As `ApplicationContext` includes all functionality of the
>   `BeanFactory`, it is generally recommended over the `BeanFactory`,
>   except for a few situations.

Also from the same [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-introduction):

> You can create `ApplicationContext` instances declaratively by using,
>   for example, a `ContextLoader`. Of course you can also create
>   `ApplicationContext` instances programmatically by using one of the
>   `ApplicationContext` implementations.
>
> You can register an `ApplicationContext` using the
>   `ContextLoaderListener` as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. A standard spring web application has two different containers: ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext